# Pandas- Comparison with SQL- Can someone please explain me this code

Tags: sql, pandas

```py
(tips[tips['tip'] < 2]\
  .assign(rnk_min=tips.groupby(['sex'])\ 
  ['tip'].rank(method='min'))\
  .query('rnk_min < 3')\
  .sort_values(['sex', 'rnk_min']))
```

Answer (score 0):

Clearly some things are clear

1. select anyone that has a tip < 2
2. create a column `assign()`
3. rank people then further filter to those with a ranking < 3

some code to generate a data set so you can experiment in a jupyter notebook

```
sex = ["Male","Female"]
s = ['Living_With_Partner','Divorced','Separated','Married','Missing','Never_Married','Widowed']
tips = pd.DataFrame([[random.randint(15,80), sex[random.randint(0,1)], s[random.randint(0,len(s)-1)], 
                    random.randint(0,50)] for r in range(200)],
            columns=["age","sex","status","tip"])

tips
(tips[tips['tip'] < 2]\
  .assign(rnk_min=tips.groupby(['sex'])\
  ['tip'].rank(method='min'))\
  .query('rnk_min < 3')\
  .sort_values(['sex', 'rnk_min']))
```